# loop output message into standard output every second while waiting for input - PTHREAD

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, fread

I am working with threads. I have a thread outputting into standard output "waiting ..." every a1 second. I am trying to write something into the standard input within my main thread, but every second when the "waiting ..." output happens it sucks in the letters i was able to write so far.
I'm really confused at this. I'm assuming that i need to output only when there is a newline detected in the standard input but i am clueless how to check for that.

the output it provides me:

```
waiting ...
waiting ...
fri <-- me trying to input friends 
friwaiting ... <-- fri gets sucked in halfway through me typing it
waiting ...
waiting ...
```

my code:

```
void* thread_one(void* arg){

    while(1){
        sleep(1);
        if (write(1, "waiting ...\n", 12) != 12) {
            write(2, "There was an error writing to standard out\n", 44);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char buffer[11];
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_one, NULL);

    while(1){
        int r = read(0, buffer, 10);
        if(r<=0){
            break;
        }
        buffer[r] = 0;
        printf("message: %s\n", buffer);

        if(strcmp(buffer, "exit\n")==0){
            break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any point in the right direction is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have to synchronize two thread read and write. In this case, the most simple is using the `mutex`. You can see the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// using the mutex "lock"
pthread_mutex_t lock;
void* thread_one(void* arg){

    while(1){
        sleep(1);
        // lock the mutex
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        if (write(1, "waiting ...\n", 12) != 12) {
            write(2, "There was an error writing to standard out\n", 44);
        }
        // unlock the mutex after writing
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char buffer[11];
    pthread_t tid;
   pthread_mutex_init(&lock], NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_one, NULL);

    while(1){
        // lock mutex to read
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        int r = read(0, buffer, 10);
        // unlock after reading
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        if(r<=0){
            break;
        }
        buffer[r] = 0;
        printf("message: %s\n", buffer);

        if(strcmp(buffer, "exit\n")==0){
            break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
waiting ...
message: friday

monday
message: monday

waiting ...
```

You can also have some knowledge in this tutorial [pthread](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15492-f07/www/pthreads.html)